# Jasper Report Pdf export

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am trying to create table in jrxml.
Number of columns in table may very ,
when I am trying to export report in PDF format ,data becomes unreadable due high number of column.
Is there any way we can export report in larger page size like A3 or can add scrolling feature to A4 size.
Note: Report need to be exported only in pdf not CSV or any other format.

Thanks , Any Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you change your report page to A3 Landscape or you can set custom page size. You can find this option in Jasperstudio Properties so you can fit more column.

[image: Jasperstudio Properties]

Comment: select the report root node in the Outline view. The report properties are shown in the Properties view.

To change the page dimensions of a report, click the Report tab in the Properties view for the report, then click Edit Page Format to open the Page Format dialog. Here you can edit the width, height, units, orientation and margins of the report.